# How to change header's title of a QTableView?

Tags: qt

Simple as that, I've been searching for hours without finding a solution. I have a `QTableView` connected to a `QStandardItemModel` and I just want to change the name it the `QTableView` headers. Now there is just 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Comment: You mean titles of columns? Why are you using QStandardItemModel? Wouldn't it be better to use/inherit QAbstractTableModel (it has header as an argument in constructor)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[QStandardItemModel::setHorizontalHeaderLabels](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#setHorizontalHeaderLabels) is probably what you need.

Comment: Oh thank you, exactly what I was searching for!